# C# Floating Point Accuracy

Tags: c#, floating-point

Trying to create a Mandelbrot set, I have been trying to using 8 and 15 digit floating point variables in my program, and have run into an issue: the `double` approximates to `0`. I tried unit testing and wrote this code to isolate the issue. Using the variable viewer, the `h` and `w` values both were on `0.0`, as opposed to `0.00185185185185` and `0.0015625`, yet when I just write `double h = 0.0015625`, it works.

Many thanks for assistance.

```
int apparentwidth = 3;
int apparentheight = 2;
int height = 1080;
int width = 1920;

double w = (apparentwidth / width);
double h = (apparentheight / height);

Console.WriteLine(w);
Console.WriteLine(h);
```

Comment: the math is being performed on integers and then you are converting to floating point. You probably want to convert before doing the math.

Answer (score 3):

You're dividing two `int` variables, and the result is an `int`. You're storing the result in a `double`, but the scale (portion after the decimal) has already been lost.

Use `double` throughout:

```
 double apparentwidth = 3;
 double apparentheight = 2;
 double height = 1080;
 double width = 1920;

 double w = (apparentwidth / width);
 double h = (apparentheight / height);
```

Or cast one of the variables to a `double` when dividing:

```
 double w = ((double)apparentwidth / width);
 double h = ((double)apparentheight / height);
```

Comment: I do not agree with using double throughout. There does not appear to be a need to use a 64 bit number here except preserving precision on divide by casting. Heck, based on what's in the OP a short would likely suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer division on accident.

```
double w = (double)apparentwidth / (double)width;
double h = (double)apparentheight / (double)height;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide further explanation to the other answers:

When you do mathematical operations on `int`s, the result is an `int`, and this is achieved by effectively truncating the non-integer portion:

```
3 / 2 == 1
```

When an operation is performed involving at least one `double`, the `int` input is first converted to a `double`, so the result is a `double`:

```
1.0 / 4 == 0.25
4 * 0.25 == 1
```

And of course, if both inputs are `double` the result is `double` and no implicit conversion occurs:

```
1.0 / 4.0 == 0.25
```